# Data provider being executed multiple times

Tags: java, testng, jboss-arquillian

I have problem with using @DataProvider in Arquillian test i'm using so I write a simple test to see how data is being executed. My goal is to execute my did a single time so there should be two prints "LOGS Data is..."

Instead i got them executed two times (four prints). I would like to ask you guys why is that and how to fix it.

Here is simple code:

```
@DataProvider(name = "addMethodDataProvider")
public Object[][] dataProviderMethod()
{
    return new Object[][] { { "param one-one", "param two-one" }, { "param one-two", "param two-two" } };

}
@Test(dataProvider = "addMethodDataProvider")
public void testMethod(String data, String data1)
{
    System.out.println("Data is: " + data + " & "+ data1 );
}
```

Output sample:

```
14:41:55,660 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Data is: param one-one & param two-one
14:41:55,777 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Data is: param one-two & param two-two
14:41:56,043 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Data is: param one-one & param two-one
14:41:56,164 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Data is: param one-two & param two-two
```

Comment: Please provide code that reproduces the issue. If I put the code sample into a test class and run it I only get two lines of parameter output as expected.

Comment: It seems like a similar problem to the Spock Test runner. Essentially it runs n^2 times where n is the size of the data set provided for the parametrized test method. I'm working on the fix for Spock at the moment and when I find one I will implement similar improvement for TestNG. I will keep you update. For your convenience you can create an issue for testng test runner in arquillian-core project on GitHub so you will be automatically notified. https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-core